# Is it possible to set a avatar for chat bot built on the google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xmpp

It's really easy to build a chat bot with python and google app engine. But a bot without a avatar is difficult to identify.

There's an XMPP protocol for exchanging user avatars: XEP-0084: User Avatar.  http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0084.html

But how to implement it? Is it possible to implement the protocol with the xmpp apis supported by GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short no.

These are the supported protocol extensions.
http://code.google.com/apis/talk/jep_extensions/extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using [XEP-0153](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html) instead.  It can be (and often is) implemented completely client-side.